# Конвертировать дату ДД / ММ / ГГГГ в ГГ-ММ-ДД Python

Tags: python, строки, файлы

Я загружаю файл, в котором хранятся даты формата ДД / ММ / ГГГГ (например 15.10.2020), каждая дата начинается с новой строки. Необходимо сделать новый новый файл на основе исходного с датами в формате ГГ-ММ-ДД.
Как можно реализовать данную задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Открываем файл с датами ДД.ММ.ГГГГ в режиме чтения
file1 = open('DD.MM.YYYY.txt','r')
# Открываем файл, куда запишем даты ГГ.ММ.ДД в режиме перезаписи
file2 = open('YY.MM.DD.txt','w')
# Получаем содержимое файла 1 и разделяем этот текст на даты
# Получившийся список дат мы перебираем
for i in file1.read().split('\n'):
    # Каждую дату мы делим ещё на дату месяц и год. После чего записываем
    # во второй файл.
    sd = i.split('.')
    file2.write(f'{sd[2][2]}{sd[2][3]}.{sd[1]}.{sd[0]}')
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from datetime import datetime

src = '20/12/2022'
d = datetime.strptime(src, '%d/%m/%Y')
dst = d.strftime('%y-%m-%d')
print(dst)
# 22-12-20
```